# XML Parse Attributes PHP $string = value ;

Tags: php, parsing

I have xml. 
It's  movie showtimes, and i try parse.

```
<shows>
    <show id="160575" film_id="7043" cinema_id="89" hall_id="241">
        <begin>2012-11-15</begin>
        <end>2012-11-18</end>
        <times>
            <time time="10:30:00">
                <prices>20, 30</prices>
                <note><![CDATA[]]></note>
            </time>
        </times>
    </show>
</shows>
```

I parse my XML and echo content  :
String "film_id_m" must be 7043 from the tag .

```
$xmlstr = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
$id_f = 89;
$cinema_id = "//show[@cinema_id=".$id_f."]";

$cinema=$x->xpath($cinema_id);

///////////string///////////////////
$begin_m = $cinema[0]->begin;
$end_m = $cinema[0]->end;
$film_id_m = ????????; 



/////////echo//////////////////////
echo "<b>BEGIN: </b>".$begin_m."<br>"; 
echo "<b>END: </b>".$end_m."<br>"; 
echo "<b>FILM ID: </b>".$film_id_m."<br>";
```

P.S: Sorry for my english.

Comment: `$cinema[0]->attributes("film_id")`

Comment: [SimpleXmlElement attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `film_id` is an attribute of the currently processed element, you can retrieve its value with either...

```
$film_id_m = $cinema[0]->attributes()->film_id;
```

... or just...

```
$film_id_m = $cinema[0]['film_id'];
```